# Máscara em input text de WebControl

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Criei um UserControl chamado UclDataVigencia bem simples. Apenas um label e dois input texts que serão responsáveis por receber uma data de início e uma data de fim. Gostaria de aplicar uma máscara para a data do tipo dd/mm/aaaa. Tentei utilizar o jQuery MaskInput, mas sem sucesso. Achei esse [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/97aa65ac-3680-4cfd-a60c-43cd8884e300/problema-com-pagina-ascx-?forum=aspnetpt), mas não tive sucesso, segue o código do UclDataVigencia_PortalTributario.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UclDataVigencia_PortalTributario.ascx.cs" Inherits="Web.Seguranca.UserControls.UclDataVigencia_PortalTributario" %>

<asp:Label ID="lb_msg" runat="server" Font-Bold="true">Data de Vigência (Mensagem de Observação)</asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="lb_dataInicio" runat="server" Font-Bold="true">Data Início:</asp:Label><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="txt_dataInicio" runat="server" ToolTip="dd/mm/aaaa" Width="25%" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="true" ></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="lb_dataFim" runat="server" Font-Bold="true">Data Fim:</asp:Label><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="txt_dataFim" runat="server" ToolTip="dd/mm/aaaa" Width="25%" CssClass="form-control" Enabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Por que o jQuery MaskInput não funcionou? Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: No solution explorer eu vejo que o script foi carregado, mas a maskara não é aplicada.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia usar javascript exemplo:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   function mascaraData(campoData){
              var data = campoData.value;
              if (data.length == 2){
                  data = data + '/';
                  document.forms[0].data.value = data;
      return true;              
              }
              if (data.length == 5){
                  data = data + '/';
                  document.forms[0].data.value = data;
                  return true;
              }
         }
</script>
```

Referencie no seu TextBox assim:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_dataInicio" runat="server"
ToolTip="dd/mm/aaaa" Width="25%"
CssClass="form-control" Enabled="true"
OnKeyUp="mascaraData(this);" maxlength="10">
</asp:TextBox><br />
```

Comment: Caso essa resposta tenha atendido suas necessidades, marque-a como resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou cara...